# Subscribe to Flux Websocket inbound connection with projectreactor blocking?

Tags: intellij-idea, websocket, nonblocking, project-reactor, reactor-netty

In the below code, IntelliJ warns the subscribe should not be called in a blocking scope. Unfortunately subscribe seems to be the most intuitive way of associating a consumer with the inbound message stream, is there a better way?

[image: Calling subscribe in non-blocking scope]

Code snippet in Kotlin, based on the example Java code in the [projectreactor documentation](https://projectreactor.io/docs/netty/snapshot/reference/index.html#_connect).

I want to subscribe to the inbound messages with a consumer that is injected, or expose the inbound messages flux in a way that other consumers can access and subscribe to it and I don't want this to be blocking.

```
import io.netty.buffer.Unpooled
import io.netty.util.CharsetUtil
import reactor.core.publisher.Flux
import reactor.netty.http.client.HttpClient

fun main() {
    HttpClient.create()
        .websocket()
        .uri("wss://echo.websocket.org")
        .handle { inbound, outbound ->
            inbound.receive()
                .asString()
                .take(1)
                .subscribe(
                    { println(it) },
                    { println("error $it") },
                    { println("completed") }
                )

            val msgBytes = "hello".toByteArray(CharsetUtil.ISO_8859_1)
            outbound.send(Flux.just(Unpooled.wrappedBuffer(msgBytes))).neverComplete()
        }
        .blockLast()
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We found an alternative to subscribe that was non-blocking. `then` and `zip`. Example in Kotlin.

```
import io.netty.buffer.Unpooled
import io.netty.util.CharsetUtil.UTF_8
import reactor.core.publisher.Flux
import reactor.netty.http.client.HttpClient

fun main() {
    val outgoingMessagesFlux = Flux.just(Unpooled.wrappedBuffer("hello".toByteArray(UTF_8)))

    HttpClient.create()
        .websocket()
        .uri("wss://echo.websocket.org")
        .handle { inbound, outbound ->
            val thenInbound = inbound.receive()
                .asString()
                .doOnNext { println(it) }
                .then()

            val thenOutbound = outbound.send(outgoingMessagesFlux).neverComplete()
            Flux.zip(thenInbound, thenOutbound).then()
        }.blockLast()
}
```

This was based on the [Spring WebFlux Netty websocket client](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/dc6f63f610ab0278c8c9d2c5c7cbbebb9928ec91/spring-webflux/src/main/java/org/springframework/web/reactive/socket/WebSocketHandler.java#L61) source code implementation and the current [spring-framework documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/web-reactive.html#webflux-websockethandler).